# Drools: rule not fired (Possible bug when using registered customized operator)

Tags: drools

I just started to use Drools (7.1.0 Beta & 7.0.0 FINAL), and wanted to apply two rules based on Soundex approximate algorithm (new customized registered function)

I run the following code with the 3 contact facts  against 4 suspect facts:

```
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieHelper kh = new KieHelper() ;
KieModuleModel kmm = ks.newKieModuleModel();
kmm.setConfigurationProperty("drools.evaluator.soundex", SoundexEvaluatorsDefinition.class.getName());
kh.setKieModuleModel(kmm);
kh.addResource(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("soundex_m1"
    + ".drl",SoundexProofConceptExample.class),ResourceType.DRL ) ;
KieBase kb =kh.build();
AgendaEventListener ael = new DebugAgendaEventListener();

KieSession ksession =kb.newKieSession();

ksession.addEventListener(ael);
//StatelessKieSession ksession =kb.newStatelessKieSession();

long totalTime = 0;

String filename;
if ( args.length != 0 ) {
    String arg = args[0];
    filename = arg;
} else {
    filename = "soundex2.dat";
}

InputStream is = SoundexProofConceptExample.class.getResourceAsStream( "data/" + filename );
List<Suspect> list = getInputObjects( is );
for ( Iterator<Suspect> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        Object object = it.next();
        ksession.insert( object );
}


ksession.insert( new Contact( "MIELI","GIOVANI",56 ));
ksession.insert( new Contact( "AMONE","DAVID",46 ));
ksession.insert( new Contact( "MOKKY","DANIEL",48 ));

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
//ksession.fireAllRules();
ksession.fireAllRules();
```

The suspect facts within the file are:

```
(Suspect (fistname AMONE) (lastname DAVI)  (age  46) (reason criminel) )
(Suspect (fistname AMONE) (lastname DAVID) (age  46) (reason criminel) )
(Suspect (fistname PAIS) (lastname JULES)   (age  35) (reason escrow) )
(Suspect (fistname MOKY) (lastname DANO)   (age  35) (reason terroriste) )
```

With the following two rules:

```
rule "Rule 01 - soundex[m1,20] " salience 50
    when
        $suspect : Suspect( $s_firstname : firstname)
        //$suspect : Suspect( )
        $contact :  Contact(firstname soundex[m1,20] $suspect.firstname &&  lastname soundex[m1,20] $suspect.lastname)

   then
        retract($contact)
        System.out.println("!!!RESULT: Contact: "+ $contact + " match suspect: " + $suspect + " drools : " + org.drools.examples.soundex.Utility.displayRule(drools));
end
rule "Rule 02 - soundex[m1,50] " salience 20
    when
         $suspect : Suspect($s_lastname: lastname)
         //$suspect : Suspect( )
         $contact :  Contact(firstname soundex[m1,50] $suspect.firstname && lastname soundex[m1,50] $suspect.lastname)

   then
        System.out.println("!!!RESULT Contact: "+ $contact + " match suspect: " + $suspect + " drools : " + org.drools.examples.soundex.Utility.displayRule(drools));
End
```

And I get to **expected** following output:

> 17:35:51.888 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.k.b.impl.KieRepositoryImpl.addKieModule:119 - KieModule was
>   added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=org.default:artifact:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
>   MIELI[M400] doesnt match[m1,20]AMONE[A550] 17:35:52.251 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.event.DebugAgendaEventListener.matchCreated:39 -
>   ==>[ActivationCreatedEvent: getActivation()=[[ Rule 01 - soundex[m1,20]  active=false ] [ [fact
>   0:6:1992801971:2009445466:6:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Contact:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46}] [fact
>   0:2:788892554:2009445466:2:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Suspect:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46,reason='criminel'}] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]
>   17:35:52.252 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.event.DebugAgendaEventListener.beforeMatchFired:47 -
>   ==>[BeforeActivationFiredEvent:  getActivation()=[[ Rule 01 - soundex[m1,20]  active=false ] [ [fact
>   0:6:1992801971:2009445466:6:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Contact:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46}] [fact
>   0:2:788892554:2009445466:2:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Suspect:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46,reason='criminel'}] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]
>   !!!RESULT: Contact: Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE', age=46}
>   match suspect: Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46,reason='criminel'} drools :  rule triggered: Rule 01 -
>   soundex[m1,20]  17:35:52.257 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.event.DebugAgendaEventListener.afterMatchFired:51 -
>   ==>[AfterActivationFiredEvent: getActivation()=[[ Rule 01 - soundex[m1,20]  active=false ] [ [fact
>   0:6:1992801971:2009445466:6:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Contact:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46}] [fact
>   0:2:788892554:2009445466:2:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Suspect:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46,reason='criminel'}] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]
>   17:35:52.261 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.event.DebugAgendaEventListener.matchCreated:39 -
>   ==>[ActivationCreatedEvent: getActivation()=[[ Rule 02 - soundex[m1,50]  active=false ] [ [fact
>   0:7:1681094402:-2139086223:7:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Contact:Person{lastname='DANIEL',firstname='MOKKY',
>   age=48}] [fact
>   0:4:1060042118:64813285:4:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Suspect:Person{lastname='DANO',firstname='MOKY',
>   age=35,reason='terroriste'}] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]
>   17:35:52.261 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.event.DebugAgendaEventListener.beforeMatchFired:47 -
>   ==>[BeforeActivationFiredEvent:  getActivation()=[[ Rule 02 - soundex[m1,50]  active=false ] [ [fact
>   0:7:1681094402:-2139086223:7:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Contact:Person{lastname='DANIEL',firstname='MOKKY',
>   age=48}] [fact
>   0:4:1060042118:64813285:4:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Suspect:Person{lastname='DANO',firstname='MOKY',
>   age=35,reason='terroriste'}] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]
>   !!!RESULT Contact: Person{lastname='DANIEL',firstname='MOKKY', age=48}
>   match suspect: Person{lastname='DANO',firstname='MOKY',
>   age=35,reason='terroriste'} drools :  rule triggered: Rule 02 -
>   soundex[m1,50]  17:35:52.263 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.event.DebugAgendaEventListener.afterMatchFired:51 -
>   ==>[AfterActivationFiredEvent: getActivation()=[[ Rule 02 - soundex[m1,50]  active=false ] [ [fact
>   0:7:1681094402:-2139086223:7:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Contact:Person{lastname='DANIEL',firstname='MOKKY',
>   age=48}] [fact
>   0:4:1060042118:64813285:4:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Suspect:Person{lastname='DANO',firstname='MOKY',
>   age=35,reason='terroriste'}] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]

Now If I change slightly the rules

```
rule "Rule 01 - soundex[m1,20] KO " salience 50
    when
        //$suspect : Suspect( $s_firstname : firstname)
        $suspect : Suspect()
        $contact :  Contact(firstname soundex[m1,20] $suspect.firstname &&  lastname soundex[m1,20] $suspect.lastname)

   then
        //retract($contact)
        System.out.println("!!!RESULT: Contact: "+ $contact + " match suspect: " + $suspect + " drools : " + org.drools.examples.soundex.Utility.displayRule(drools));
end
rule "Rule 02 - soundex[m1,50] KO" salience 20
    when
         //$suspect : Suspect()
         $suspect : Suspect()
         $contact :  Contact(firstname soundex[m1,50] $suspect.firstname && lastname soundex[m1,50] $suspect.lastname)

   then
        System.out.println("!!!RESULT Contact: "+ $contact + " match suspect: " + $suspect + " drools : " + org.drools.examples.soundex.Utility.displayRule(drools));
end
```

It seems that rule 02 is never triggered as you can see bellow

> 4:56:22.534 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.event.DebugAgendaEventListener.matchCreated:39 -
>   ==>[ActivationCreatedEvent: getActivation()=[[ Rule 01 - soundex[m1,20] KO  active=false ] [ [fact
>   0:6:1387620926:2009445466:6:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Contact:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46}] [fact
>   0:2:1971152916:2009445466:2:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Suspect:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46,reason='criminel'}] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]
>   14:56:22.534 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.event.DebugAgendaEventListener.beforeMatchFired:47 -
>   ==>[BeforeActivationFiredEvent:  getActivation()=[[ Rule 01 - soundex[m1,20] KO  active=false ] [ [fact
>   0:6:1387620926:2009445466:6:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Contact:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46}] [fact
>   0:2:1971152916:2009445466:2:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Suspect:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46,reason='criminel'}] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]
>   !!!RESULT: Contact: Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE', age=46}
>   match suspect: Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46,reason='criminel'} drools :  rule triggered: Rule 01 -
>   soundex[m1,20] KO  14:56:22.539 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.event.DebugAgendaEventListener.afterMatchFired:51 -
>   ==>[AfterActivationFiredEvent: getActivation()=[[ Rule 01 - soundex[m1,20] KO  active=false ] [ [fact
>   0:6:1387620926:2009445466:6:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Contact:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46}] [fact
>   0:2:1971152916:2009445466:2:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Suspect:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46,reason='criminel'}] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]
>   14:56:22.540 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.event.DebugAgendaEventListener.matchCreated:39 -
>   ==>[ActivationCreatedEvent: getActivation()=[[ Rule 02 - soundex[m1,50] KO active=false ] [ [fact
>   0:6:1387620926:2009445466:6:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Contact:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46}] [fact
>   0:2:1971152916:2009445466:2:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Suspect:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46,reason='criminel'}] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]
>   14:56:22.540 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.event.DebugAgendaEventListener.beforeMatchFired:47 -
>   ==>[BeforeActivationFiredEvent:  getActivation()=[[ Rule 02 - soundex[m1,50] KO active=false ] [ [fact
>   0:6:1387620926:2009445466:6:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Contact:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46}] [fact
>   0:2:1971152916:2009445466:2:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Suspect:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46,reason='criminel'}] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]
>   !!!RESULT Contact: Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE', age=46}
>   match suspect: Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46,reason='criminel'} drools :  rule triggered: Rule 02 -
>   soundex[m1,50] KO 14:56:22.541 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.event.DebugAgendaEventListener.afterMatchFired:51 -
>   ==>[AfterActivationFiredEvent: getActivation()=[[ Rule 02 - soundex[m1,50] KO active=false ] [ [fact
>   0:6:1387620926:2009445466:6:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Contact:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46}] [fact
>   0:2:1971152916:2009445466:2:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.soundex.Suspect:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46,reason='criminel'}] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]`

It seems that something is not reinitialized/rewinded when the suspect pickup declaration is identical?

Now I did the same kind of test but this time with “standard” operator like soundslike or even == and I everythin is ok and I don’t have to pickup suspect with a difference synthax:

Here are the “standard” rules:

A)

```
 import org.drools.examples.bug.Person;
    import org.drools.examples.bug.Suspect;


    rule "Rule 01 - firstname and lastname"
        when
            $suspect : Suspect()
            //$suspect : Suspect( $s_firstname : firstname, $s_lastname : lastname)
            $contact :  Contact(firstname soundslike $suspect.firstname && lastname soundslike $suspect.lastname)

       then
            retract($contact)
            System.out.println("!!!RESULT: Contact: "+ $contact + " match suspect: "  + " drools : Rule 01 - firstname and lastname");
    end
    rule "Rule 02 - firstname or lastname"
        when
             //$suspect : Suspect( $s_firstname : firstname, $s_lastname : lastname)
             $suspect : Suspect()
             $contact :  Contact(firstname soundslike $suspect.firstname || lastname soundslike $suspect.lastname)

       then
            System.out.println("!!!RESULT Contact: "+ $contact + " match suspect: " + $suspect + " drools : Rule 02 - firstname or lastname");
    End
```

B)

```
import org.drools.examples.bug.Person;
import org.drools.examples.bug.Suspect;


rule "Rule 01 - firstname and lastname"
    when
        $suspect : Suspect()
        //$suspect : Suspect( $s_firstname : firstname, $s_lastname : lastname)
        $contact :  Contact(firstname == $suspect.firstname && lastname == $suspect.lastname)

   then
        retract($contact)
        System.out.println("!!!RESULT: Contact: "+ $contact + " match suspect: "  + " drools : Rule 01 - firstname and lastname");
end
rule "Rule 02 - firstname or lastname"
    when
         //$suspect : Suspect( $s_firstname : firstname, $s_lastname : lastname)
         $suspect : Suspect()
         $contact :  Contact(firstname == $suspect.firstname || lastname == $suspect.lastname)

   then
        System.out.println("!!!RESULT Contact: "+ $contact + " match suspect: " + $suspect + " drools : Rule 02 - firstname or lastname");
end
```

I run the following code:

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieHelper kh = new KieHelper() ;
    KieModuleModel kmm = ks.newKieModuleModel();
    kh.setKieModuleModel(kmm);
    kh.addResource(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("Bug1"
        + ".drl",Bug1.class),ResourceType.DRL ) ;
    KieBase kb =kh.build();
    AgendaEventListener ael = new DebugAgendaEventListener();

    KieSession ksession =kb.newKieSession();

    ksession.addEventListener(ael);

    long totalTime = 0;


    ksession.insert(new Suspect("AMONE","DAVI",46,"C1"));
    ksession.insert(new Suspect("PAIS","JULES",35,"C2"));
    ksession.insert(new Suspect("MOKKY","DANO",35,"C1"));
    ksession.insert(new Suspect("AMONE","DAVID",46,"C3"));


    ksession.insert( new Contact( "MIELI","GIOVANI",56 ));
    ksession.insert( new Contact( "AMONE","DAVID",46 ));
    ksession.insert( new Contact( "MOKKY","DANIEL",48 ));


    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ksession.fireAllRules();
```

Everything’s seems to be ok even if I change the syntax to pick up the suspect fact as I did for the earlier example with my customized operator.

> 10:33:05.061 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.k.b.impl.KieRepositoryImpl.addKieModule:119 - KieModule was
>   added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=org.default:artifact:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
>   10:33:05.434 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.event.DebugAgendaEventListener.matchCreated:39 -
>   ==>[ActivationCreatedEvent: getActivation()=[[ Rule 01 - firstname and lastname active=false ] [ [fact
>   0:6:413373997:2009445466:6:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.bug.Contact:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46}] [fact
>   0:4:1380976928:2009445466:4:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.bug.Suspect:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46,reason='C3'}] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]
>   10:33:05.435 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.event.DebugAgendaEventListener.beforeMatchFired:47 -
>   ==>[BeforeActivationFiredEvent:  getActivation()=[[ Rule 01 - firstname and lastname active=false ] [ [fact
>   0:6:413373997:2009445466:6:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.bug.Contact:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46}] [fact
>   0:4:1380976928:2009445466:4:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.bug.Suspect:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46,reason='C3'}] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]
>   !!!RESULT: Contact: Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE', age=46}
>   match suspect:  drools : Rule 01 - firstname and lastname 10:33:05.441
>   [main] INFO  o.d.c.event.DebugAgendaEventListener.afterMatchFired:51 -
>   ==>[AfterActivationFiredEvent: getActivation()=[[ Rule 01 - firstname and lastname active=false ] [ [fact
>   0:6:413373997:2009445466:6:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.bug.Contact:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46}] [fact
>   0:4:1380976928:2009445466:4:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.bug.Suspect:Person{lastname='DAVID',firstname='AMONE',
>   age=46,reason='C3'}] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]
>   10:33:05.469 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.event.DebugAgendaEventListener.matchCreated:39 -
>   ==>[ActivationCreatedEvent: getActivation()=[[ Rule 02 - firstname or lastname active=false ] [ [fact
>   0:7:2024711353:-2139086223:7:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.bug.Contact:Person{lastname='DANIEL',firstname='MOKKY',
>   age=48}] [fact
>   0:3:1032568028:64813285:3:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.bug.Suspect:Person{lastname='DANO',firstname='MOKKY',
>   age=35,reason='C1'}] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]
>   10:33:05.469 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.event.DebugAgendaEventListener.beforeMatchFired:47 -
>   ==>[BeforeActivationFiredEvent:  getActivation()=[[ Rule 02 - firstname or lastname active=false ] [ [fact
>   0:7:2024711353:-2139086223:7:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.bug.Contact:Person{lastname='DANIEL',firstname='MOKKY',
>   age=48}] [fact
>   0:3:1032568028:64813285:3:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.bug.Suspect:Person{lastname='DANO',firstname='MOKKY',
>   age=35,reason='C1'}] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]
>   !!!RESULT Contact: Person{lastname='DANIEL',firstname='MOKKY', age=48}
>   match suspect: Person{lastname='DANO',firstname='MOKKY',
>   age=35,reason='C1'} drools : Rule 02 - firstname or lastname
>   10:33:05.471 [main] INFO 
>   o.d.c.event.DebugAgendaEventListener.afterMatchFired:51 -
>   ==>[AfterActivationFiredEvent: getActivation()=[[ Rule 02 - firstname or lastname active=false ] [ [fact
>   0:7:2024711353:-2139086223:7:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.bug.Contact:Person{lastname='DANIEL',firstname='MOKKY',
>   age=48}] [fact
>   0:3:1032568028:64813285:3:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:org.drools.examples.bug.Suspect:Person{lastname='DANO',firstname='MOKKY',
>   age=35,reason='C1'}] ] ], getKnowledgeRuntime()=KieSession[0]]

thx for your findings/help/answers

Comment: The two rules after "Now If I change slightly the rules " and the ones after "B)" are identical (except for "salience 1" in the first set) but you say that the first code does not work and the second does? Please check.

Comment: Sorry , case A) and B) with "standard" operator  like == and soundslike are fine . I din correct  with the applied rules with same "saliance", but with different rule's names for more understandability.